# How to insert a clickable hyperlink with Outlook AddIn?

Tags: html, hyperlink, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook AddIn which pastes a text in the body of email.
I am not using any of the following.

```
email.Body 
email.HTMLBody
```

Instead, I use:
 `email.GetInspector.WordEditor.Content.InsertBefore()`or InsertAfter()
The reason of that choice is justified by the fact that the latter mentioned line of code keeps the email formatting, the default user's fonts, as well as the signature formatting.

Now, when I try to paste a link into the email, it doesn't appear as a hyperlink, but just as a string. My link only becomes a clickable hyperlink when I click space or enter after it.
I can't use the URI class because I am also pasting text in a string format along with the link.

I tried to add the tags myself and saved the email as .htm here is the line where my link is posted. The tags are not translated into HTML.

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://whatever.com&quot;&gt;http://whatever.com&lt;/a&gt;
```

And if  don't put the tags myself, it's just the same thing, but without all the  &quot, &gt, &lt... and of course no HTML tag, which makes no clickable hyperlink.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The Document class from the Word object model provides the [Hyperlinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837239(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a Hyperlinks collection that represents all the hyperlinks in the specified document.

You need to use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837214(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Hyperlinks class. It returns a Hyperlink object that represents a new hyperlink added to a range, selection, or document.

Comment: Could you please explain more or exhibit an example of code. I am having trouble with this.

Comment: The WordEditor property returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model. You can use the WordEditor.Hyperlinks.Add method to add a new hyperlink.

Comment: I’m still lost here.
When I tried this 
`email.GetInspector.WordEditor.Hyperlinks.Add(0).Address = link;`
 I get this error: “Could not convert argument 0 for call to Add.”

Should I call `Hyperlinks.Add(0)` before or after (or even insteadof ) inserting the link through `InsertAfter(link)` ?


When I use this line 
`email.GetInspector.WordEditor.Hyperlinks.Item(0);`
 I get this error: 
 “The requested member of the collection does not exist.”